# SQL Server 2012 Visualization of Table relationships

Tags: sql-server-2012

Does SQL Server 2012 /2014 have a way of creating a visualization of the table relationships of a database ?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can create Database Diagrams with the relationships on tables. 
This is per database, and not on the Instance level.

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/create-a-new-database-diagram-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-2017)